# Travelling back to India with a phone purchased (and unboxed) in Netherlands

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items

I am in Netherlands on tourist visa and wanted to buy a iPhone and go back to India. I would claiming the VAT return at Amsterdam Airport but do I need to declare in India and do I need to pay the duty??

I will be using this phone so this phone wont be sealed packed.

Comment: If you unbox and use the phone in the Netherlands, as I understand it, you will be ineligible for a VAT refund.  I don't know how carefully they check these things.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are importing a new device into India.  Using it before coming home doesn't absolve you of duty.